# UITableview not updating values after adding observer?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a Two **UIViewController**

**UIViewController-1** and **UIViewController-2**

**UIViewController-1** will have **UIButton** name as filter

When i click **filter button**,it will add **UIViewController-2** UIView into **UIViewController-1**

**By this code**

```
- (IBAction)filterAction:(id)sender {
    if (isDown==NO) {
        isDown=YES;
        UIViewController* rvc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SearchCriteriaViewController"];
        self.overlayView=rvc.view;
        CGRect rect=self.overlayView.frame;
        rect.origin.y=self.overlayView.frame.origin.y+110;
        rect.size.height=self.overlayView.frame.size.height-160;
        self.overlayView.frame=rect;
        [self addChildViewController:rvc];
        [self.view addSubview:self.overlayView];
        [rvc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    } else {
        isDown=NO;
        [self.overlayView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

its working good.

**UIViewController-2** has some process with **UIButton** name as filter.

When i clicking **filter button**,it will get some values from server and store it into **NSDictonary**.

I want to pass value to **UIViewController-1**

so that i am using **NSNotificationCenter** class

First removed **UIViewController-2** then i have posted notification.

```
[self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self removeFromParentViewController];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"postArrayObject" object:response];
```

In **UIViewController-1** i am getting Observer.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(objFirstViewController:) name:nil object:nil];
}

-(void)objFirstViewController:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if ([[notification name]isEqualToString:@"postArrayObject"]) {
        self.arrayFromSearch=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:(NSMutableArray *)[notification object]];
        NSLog(@"%@",self.arrayFromSearch);
        [eventList removeAllObjects];
        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;
        for (NSDictionary *dic in self.arrayFromSearch) {
            dictionary=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [dictionary setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"eventDate"] forKey:@"EVENTDATE"];
            [dictionary setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"eventId"] forKey:@"EVENTID"];
            if ([[dic valueForKey:@"country"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
                [dictionary setObject:@"" forKey:@"COUNTRY"];
            }else{
                [dictionary setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"country"] forKey:@"COUNTRY"];
            }if ([[dic valueForKey:@"eventImage"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
                [dictionary setObject:@"" forKey:@"EVENTIMAGE"];
            }else{
                [dictionary setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"eventImage"] forKey:@"EVENTIMAGE"];
            }if([[dic valueForKey:@"state"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
                [dictionary setObject:@"" forKey:@"STATE"];
            }else{
                [dictionary setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"state"] forKey:@"STATE"];
            }
            [dictionary setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"eventName"] forKey:@"EVENTNAME"];
            [dictionary setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"eventTime"] forKey:@"EVENTTIME"];
            [dictionary setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"isFeature"] forKey:@"FEATURE"];
            [dictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dic valueForKey:@"latitue"]] forKey:@"LAT"];
            [dictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dic valueForKey:@"langitude"]] forKey:@"LANG"];
            [eventList addObject:dictionary];
        }

        // [self.listTableView reloadData];
        // [self.listTableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadTable) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.listTableView reloadData];
        });

        previousSeletedIndex=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"last"];
        if (previousSeletedIndex>5) {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]removeObjectForKey:@"last"];
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:previousSeletedIndex inSection:0];

            [self.listTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                                      atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
                                              animated:YES];
        }else{
        }
    }
    else{            
    }
}
```

Everthing called and i am getting values from **Notificaton Object** and store it into local **NSMutableArray**.

When i reload the UITableView not updating a values

**But datasource and delegates are called.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `name` when you add the observer like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                      selector:@selector(objFirstViewController:) 
                                      name:@"postArrayObject" 
                                      object:nil];
```

Comment: whenever u addObserver u add with name.

Comment: i think,thats what i have done,the problem is not updating data

Comment: @vaibby karthik was able to call his observer by his observer-name and successfully load the datasource with the new list of array though, but he couldn't update the table view while reloading it to update the new items. karthik correct me if my understanding is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found solution for this.
I dont know exact reason but my understanding 
 it was blocking the main thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.listTableView reloadData];
        });
        [self.listTableView setNeedsLayout];
```

by adding this code, its woking